# Label for sonata admin embedded add button

Tags: sonata-admin

Is there a way to change the label for 'Add new' buttons when embedding collections in sonata admin? I have a couple of nested forms and the buttons are confusing for the user to say the list

Answer (score 0):

Copy file 
`sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/translations/SonataAdminBundle.[your_language].xliff` 
to 
`app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/translations/SonataAdminBundle.[your_language].xliff`

Find the key `link_action_create` and change the the target text:

```
        <trans-unit id="link_action_create">
            <source>link_action_create</source>
            <target>Add new</target> //Change to what ever you want.
        </trans-unit>
```

If values do not change Clear cache, sometimes the old values from cache are shown:
`php bin/console cache:clear`